# SQL select with case when and join table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 table in sql (postgresql)

tbl1 :

| dates | roomid | stok |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-15 | A01 | 3 |
| 2021-03-16 | A01 | 3 |
| 2021-03-17 | A01 | 3 |

tbl2 :

| bookingcode | startdate | enddate | roomid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B001 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-17 | A01 |

My syntax like this

```
select dates, tbl1.roomid,
case
    when dates between startdate and enddate - integer '1' then stok -1
else stok
end stok
from tbl1
join tbl2
on tbl1.roomid = tbl2.roomid  order by dates asc
```

When the number of booking is one **(tbl2)**, it matches **results like this** . The results are correct

| dates | roomid | stok |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-15 | A01 | 2 |
| 2021-03-16 | A01 | 2 |
| 2021-03-17 | A01 | 3 |

But when the booking is 2, it's like this (tbl2)

| bookingcode | startdate | enddate | roomid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B001 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-17 | A01 |
| B002 | 2021-03-15 | 2021-03-17 | A01 |

The result is like this, the results are not suitable

| dates | roomid | stok |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-15 | A01 | 2 |
| 2021-03-15 | A01 | 2 |
| 2021-03-16 | A01 | 2 |
| 2021-03-16 | A01 | 2 |
| 2021-03-17 | A01 | 3 |
| 2021-03-17 | A01 | 3 |

**The results I want when booking 2 are like this**

| dates | roomid | stok |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-15 | A01 | 1 |
| 2021-03-16 | A01 | 1 |
| 2021-03-17 | A01 | 3 |

**Can anyone come up with a solution?**

Comment: If you don't want a mysql answer, don't tag the question with it.

Comment: well sir I corrected the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update the database just do

```sql
UPDATE tbl1 SET stok = stok - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1.roomid = tbl2.roomid AND tbl1.dates >= tbl2.startdate AND tbl1.dates < tbl2.enddate);
```

otherwise do

```sql
SELECT dates, roomid, stok - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl1.roomid = tbl2.roomid AND tbl1.dates >= tbl2.startdate AND tbl1.dates < tbl2.enddate) FROM tbl1;
```

Comment: I know this may not be the best solution because it takes O(n²) time complexity.

Comment: BIG THX!! Its work, thx u :D @graphemecluster

Comment: I edited the second method as joining tables is not needed.